# How to number verses?

Tags: verse

In [Format verses with incrementing counters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629462) it was asked about numbering verses. I responded that the `verse` package might help, which I still think it could do so, but since then I have been wondering about terminology before trying to improve the `verse` package. What is the generally approved distinction between *poem*, *verse* and *stanza*? I now feel that the `verse` package conflates all three and "numbering" verses leads to several options.

The basic LaTeX `verse` environment enables the typesetting of one or more bunches of multiline texts. The `verse` package adds some further facilities to this such as providing a `\poemtitle{<text>}` macro.

Now a poem may consist of a single multiline text or several of them.

In some cases within a poem a multiline text is called a *stanza*. But in other cases each multiline text is called *verse*.

When folk ask about numbering verses are they asking about numbering the first item in a poem, or about the stanzas in a collection (`verse`) of them? Here is an example produced via `verse`. What should (not) be numbered?
[image]

My apologies, my computer went in to a coma and I had to get another and I'm  still trying to get everything working again. For instance I have not yet been able to reduce the graphic to a reasonable size.

I realise that this might be out of scope as it regards opinions but I hope that someone might help with the enhancement of the `verse` package.

I have been able to create code that numbers verses (whatever they might be) on either the left or right but I do not like my current user interface (zero a counter and then increment it for each `verse`). Any ideas about the user interface?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have slightly edited my question. I have code to put numbers to the left or right of a verse but I'm not sure about the user interface. Is a stanza a single group of multiline texts? Is a verse a single group of multiline texts or can it be a group of stanzas? When verses are asked to be numbered is it individual stanzas or a group of stanzas comprising a verse? And can a poem consists of a single verse (stanza) or multiple verses (stanzas)?  Basically I'm confused about the terminology which doesn't help any users of the `verse` package.

Comment: First, if you want the line numbers to appear you need to specify `\poemlines{1}` (for every line, page 7).  Effectively, a stanza consists of one or more verses, the last of which is terminated by `\\!` (page 6).  The only effect is that the line numbers restart from 1.  The counter is `poemlines`.

Answer (score 1):

First a thank you to @JohnKormylo for his input. I think that my problem might principally be with the definitions of *poem*, *verse* and *stanza*. In the *Chambers Twentieth Century Dictionary* these names all occur in the definitions of all the names, so seemingly interchangeable. ( I think that this is what is known as a "vicious circle".)

However the code below is a suggested extension to the `verse` package letting the user decide when and where to put a verse number.

```
% verseprob.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

% put something after the verse line (adjust the \hskip as appropriate)
\newcommand{\flagverseR}[1]{%
  \hskip1.5\versewidth\rlap{#1}\hskip-1.5\versewidth}

% counter for verse number
\newcounter{vscntr}
\newcommand{\zeroverse}{\setcounter{vscntr}{0}} % zero the number
\newcommand{\upverse}{\refstepcounter{vscntr}} % increment the number


\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{In a cavern, in a canyon}
\poemtitle{Clementine}
\zeroverse % zero the verse number
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  \begin{altverse} \upverse % increment the verse number
\flagverse{\thevscntr} In a cavern, in a canyon, \\ % put verse number at the left
    Excavating for a mine, \\
    Lived a miner, forty-niner, \\
    And his daugther, Clementine. \\!
  \end{altverse}

  \begin{altverse} \upverse % increment the verse number
\flagverseR{\thevscntr}   Oh my darling, Oh my darling \\ % put verse number after the line
    Oh my darling Clementine. \\
    Thou art lost and gone forever, \\
    Oh my darling Clementine. \\!
  \end{altverse}
  \end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think that this avoids any mixed interpretations of poem, verse and syntax.

I will be grateful for any further comments/disagreements about all this.